# How to list all inodes and blocks in file system which are available for unprivileged user

Tags: fedora, filesystems, stat, xfs

I'm trying to list all inodes and blocks in certain file system which are available and unused for unprivileged user. I tried `stat -f` but from what I've read it list nodes and block available for all user in the system.

Comment: Just......why ?

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to get such a list, at least not without low-level tools that are specific to each filesystem type and which are normally intended as debug or emergency repair tools.

Filesystems simply don't have any API for querying or listing free/unused inodes. Many filesystem types don't even have the concept of a fixed number of extant inodes on the filesystem, but rather create them on demand.

The best you will get is `df -i`, which produces a count of how many inodes are available (if that makes sense for the filesystem type), but you cannot enumerate them.